# how to send a particular text on click of particular layout from one activity to another

Tags: android

If I select easy layout then the textview in secoundactivity should display "EASY" and if I select normal layout then textview in secoundactivity should display "NORMAL" on it.there is only one textview in secoundactivity and it should display the text as per the click on layout
i.e send a particular text on click of particular layout from one activity to another

[image]

Mainactivity.xml

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layouteasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#456636"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="easy"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/easytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EASY"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffb9b9"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutnormal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#334556"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="normal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">




 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/normaltext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NORMAL"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#6afa73"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>]
```

Comment: Use Intent to go to new activity and `intent.putExtra()` to send some data to new activity and then in new activity retreive that data. [Read this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//In the first activity
//for easy textview
public void easy(View v){
String text=((TextView)v).getText().toString();
Intent i=new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Text",text);
startActivity(i);
}

//for Normal textview
public void Normal(View v){
String text=((TextView)v).getText().toString();
Intent i=new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Text",text);
startActivity(i);
}

//in the second activity main class get the text using the code
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("Text");
//to set text in second activity
TextView myTextView=findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
myTextView.setText(s);
```

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) for more info on intents.

Comment: in SecoundActivity i have a textview and i want to setText.  If i clicked on the easy layout then i can setText as "easy" on my textview but what if i want to click on normal layout i want to set text as "normal" i want want either of them. Means if i select easy layout then the textview in my secound activity should display easy and if i select normal layout my textview in  second activity should display normal ..

Comment: The above code is for same. I noticed that for both the views in MainActivity.xml you had android:onClick="easy". This means that whenever those views will be clicked easy(View v) method will be called where v is the View that is clicked(can be a button, textview, etc.).

Comment: also to go to the second activity you need an intent. See the link I pasted above for more info on intents.

Comment: ok actually my bad for one view i have onclick easy and for other i have onclick normal

Comment: doesn't matters, check the edited code. Even if the onClick method name was same for both of them it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = easytext.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.class, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", text);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

then in your second Activity in oncreate() methode

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
```

Comment: in SecoundActivity i have a textview and i want to setText.  If i clicked on the easy layout then i can setText as "easy" on my textview but what if i want to click on normal layout i want to set text as "normal" i want want either of them. Means if i select easy layout then the textview in my secound activity should display easy and if i select normal layout my textview in  second activity should display normal ..